# Captuing job ID when submitting Perl-generated scripts to SGE

Tags: perl, qsub, sungridengine

Perl can't open command pipes that run both in and out, which causes a problem when submitting to SGE via qsub because I lose the job id of my submission. How can I submit a generated script to SGE **and** capture the job ID that SGE assigns it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Perl FAQ: [How can I open a pipe both to and from a command?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq8#How_can_I_open_a_pipe_both_to_and_from_a_command?) (Short answer: see [`IPC::Open2`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen2))

Another approach is to use the I/O redirection facilities in your shell to capture the output of your external program:

```
open my $qsub_proc, '|-', "qsub $command $args > some/file";
print {$qsub_proc} $the_input_to_the_command;
close $qsub_proc;

open my $qsub_fh, '<', 'some/file';
my @qsub_output = <$qsub_fh>;
... # now parse @qsub_output to get your job id
```